# PHP include best practices question

Tags: php, include

I have been learning syntax for PHP and practicing it.  I come from a .NET background so masterpages always made things pretty easy for me when it came to headers and footers.

So far I have a mainHeader.php and mainFooter.php  which have my head menu and my footer html.  I created a mainBody.php and at the top I put

```
<?php include "mainHeader.php" ?>
```

and for the footer I put

```
<?php include "mainFooter.php" ?>
```

This worked perfectly and made me smile because my pages all came together nicely.  the mainHeader has my `<html>` and `<body>` and my mainFooter has my closing tags for those.

Is this good practice?

Comment: Those filenames should be enclosed in quotes, no?

Comment: Yes, otherwise they will evaluate as concatenated string definition, issue a warning, and include `mainHeaderphp` and `mainFooterphp` (no dots).

Comment: thank you.  yes they are in quotes, just didnt type them out here.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I include my views from my controllers. I also define file locations to make maintenance easier.

**config.php**

```
define('DIR_BASE',      dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM',    DIR_BASE . 'system/');
define('DIR_VIEWS',     DIR_SYSTEM . 'views/');
define('DIR_CTLS',      DIR_SYSTEM . 'ctls/');
define('DIR_MDLS',      DIR_SYSTEM . 'mdls/');
define('VIEW_HEADER',   DIR_VIEWS . 'header.php');
define('VIEW_NAVIGATION',   DIR_VIEWS . 'navigation.php');
define('VIEW_FOOTER',   DIR_VIEWS . 'footer.php');
```

Now I have all the info I need just by including `config.php`.

**controller.php**

```
require '../config.php';
include DIR_MDLS . 'model.php';

$model = new model();
if ( $model->getStuff() ) {
    $page_to_load = DIR_VIEWS . 'page.php';
}
else {
    $page_to_load = DIR_VIEWS . 'otherpage.php';
}

include VIEW_HEADER;
include VIEW_NAVIGATION;
include DIR_VIEWS . $page_to_load;
include VIEW_FOOTER;
```

Comment: Quick question: are you using a framework?  I'm trying codeigniter and I'm wondering if it is required of me to define these directory info in the config.php?

Comment: no thats using my own "framework".  you don't have to do that with code igniter

Comment: Why are you using `dirname()` twice?

Answer (score 5):

You can also do it the other way round. Have a main page with header/footer and include only the body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include $page ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahh I can see how this would be useful for generating dynamic data.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

To summarize all the above.
That's good way to use includes, but do not forget to use a template page for the page contents.

Partly based on Galen's and Balus':

`page.php`

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../config.php';
$data = get_data(); // assume we get all required data here.
$pagetitle = "This is a sample page";
$template = "page.tpl.php";
include "main.tpl.php";
```

`main.tpl.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
    <head> 
         <title><?php echo $pagetitle?></title>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <?php include $template ?> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

`page.tpl.php` something like this:

```
<h1><?php echo $pagetitle?></h1>
<?php if (!$data): ?>
No news yet :-(
<?php else: ?>
<ul>
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?>
<li><a href="news.php?id=<?php echo $row['name']?>"><?php echo $row['name']?></a></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is ok until you start using "Views" or "Templates" in which case you no longer arrange your content HTML inside the "controller" or "action" running.

Instead you will load a view and populate it with values which leaves all the HTML source ordering to the view and not your PHP file.

```
$view = new View('layout.php');
$view->header = $header;
$view->content = 'This is the main content!';
$view->footer = $footer;
print $view;
```

which then loads the layout file which looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"><?php print $header; ?></div>
        <div id="content"><?php print $content; ?></div>
        <div id="footer"><?php print $footer; ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great. Just happened to be wondering how you could organize Views and their HTML counterparts.

Comment: Why hadn't i thought of this! This is great.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is form 2010 and things have changed in the past ten years.

The way to go, now with [composer](https://getcomposer.org) having replaced most hand wired autoloaders, the best practice is to use a single `require_once` utilizing `__DIR__` from a script in a fixed, known place:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Using `define()` is not common anymore.

According to the environment agnostic approach, dependencies from the environment get injected to the application using `.env` or similiar.

Answer (score 2):

The good practice nowadays is to use a templating engine, such as [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). For the whole application consider using a [framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_frameworks#PHP), like [codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/).

Comment: couldnt disagree more about smarty

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm having bad times myself with it :) it was just the first example of a templating engine that came across my mind. And after suggesting to use a framework I didn't think the templating engine example matters that much, so I didn't think much over that. Thanks for the feedback anyway : )

Comment: I don't like smarty much, but the idea of using a templating engine is great. Except with PHP... since PHP is already a templating engine, it's kind of weird. Still, the MVC type pattern is so much better... um... let's all just use a framework! But h20 templates is pretty cool for PHP.

Comment: However much you like or dislike a particular template engine, using one to handle variable substitution, loops, conditionals, and sub-templates / includes / macros as markup (vs php code) is a huge advance IMO. I use PHPTAL, and I'm sure plenty of people hate it, too, but templates are your php equivalent to master pages.

Comment: Here to second CodeIgniter. It makes coding in PHP well-structured for those of us who tend to list off the beaten path a bit. Alternatively, the OP could check out Kohana.

Comment: @grossvogel i can do all that stuff with php...and it won't add a layer of complexity, or another "language" to learn.

Comment: Smarty is PHP written in PHP. While PHP is perfect template engine itself.

Comment: @Galen: Of course you can, but sometimes it's nice to bring in a mature library that does just what you want instead of rolling your own. I've done lots of smaller sites where your approach suits me just fine, but for the huge application I spend most of my time on, the handful of hours learning PHPTAL (which is basically just xml) has already been worth it a hundred times over.

Comment: @grossvogel Now php developers that may have to maintain it in the future must spend hours learning phptal as well.  I just feel I haven't seen anything done in templates that can't easily be done in native php

Comment: Smarty, PHPTemplate, or any other templating engine is meant to enforce separation of concerns when multiple people are working on a project.  It allows the PHP developer to hide business logic and only expose certain bits to the front end developer.  If you are the only person working on the project, Smarty is an unnecessary layer of complexity.

Comment: Regarding frameworks, CodeIgniter is a good framework to learn on but has very little out-of-box functionality when compared to Yii.  CodeIgniter's default cookie handling is also absurdly insecure.  Yii is almost identical in architecture to CI but includes scaffolding, built in Active Record, a robust User module, front-end widgets, and native jQuery support.

Answer (score 1):

For small sites, include/include_once and require/require_once are great, I haven't built a site without them in years.  I would, however, recommend making sure each of your include files is a discrete code block that is valid XML.  What I mean is don't open a tag in one include and close it in another, or vice versa - it will make changes complex and more prone to break things because you have dependencies between files.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly fine method, as long as your site doesn't outgrow the 20 pages threshold. I'd however advise to use include() in function style, not as construct, and place these templates in a separate subfolder. If there is no PHP code in them, also use a .htm file extension (htm designating partial html).

```
 include("template/main/header.htm");   // would still parse PHP code!
```

The disadvantage with this approach is, that you somewhen end up injecting HTML through global variables into it. `$HEAD='<link...>'; include("../header.htm")`. Which is not bad per se, but can quickly amass cruft.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late, just wanted to add my "pennies worth" to this question.

My suggestion would be to create methods for this, e.g my root is: var/www/htdocs/ and the functions file is in includes/functions/template-parts.php.
My functions would look as such:

```
<?php

define("DOC_ROOT", "/var/www/htdocs/"); # Add a trailing slash to make it a little easier

function GetHeader()
{
    return include DOC_ROOT . 'includes/parts/header.htm'; # Header found at include/parts/header.htm
}

function GetFooter()
{
    return include DOC_ROOT . 'includes/parts/footer.htm'; # Footer found at include/parts/footer.htm
}

?>
```

And used as such:

```
<?php

# From the main page (/var/www/htdocs/index.php)
require_once 'includes/functions/template-parts.php';
GetHeader();
?>
<!-- Page content -->
<?php

GetFooter();

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I like using functions to print headers and footers instead of includes. You can fine tune the variable scope better that way.

Comment: That's your answer?