# How to include a file with the absolute path always using PHP

Tags: php, include-path

have a file that is included in a required file. the problem that I am having is the included file work only if the user on pages that are located on the root directory of the site. but if te user branch out to a sub directory they I get the error

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

this is how I currently include the file with in the required file.

```
include('classes/browser_detection.php')
```

so I tried couple of thing which did not work

First:

```
include('/cms/classes/browser_detection.php')
```

second:

```
include( dirname(__DIR__) . '/classes/browser_detection.php')
```

both of those options did not work. How can I get it to work without having to include the class in every page individually where the main file is required?

Comment: use an absolute path like `'/home/mywebsite/public_html/cms/classes/browser_detection.php'`

Comment: if the file is accessible relative to the document root of your web server you can use `include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/cms/classes/browser_detection.php");`

Comment: An include is not only dependent on the file you want to include but also on the file that is including. It's a relation between those two and the path you use should reflect that. So for you have not told in your question the path of the script where it works and the path of the script where the problem arises. If you add those two (and the include line where it works and then works not for the second - the first, right?) then it should be no problem to just show you where the little mistake is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see answer: [PHP Directories - Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3644687/2250141)

I like to use:

config.php (sits in the root)

```
define('ROOT_SYS',dirname(__FILE__).'/'); //$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] for root access
```

this allows me to work on the site locally and on the hosting with no issues. In your case it would look something like:

```
include(ROOT_SYS . 'classes/browser_detection.php')
```

Comment: This did not work. My Server is a Windows server and not Lunix. I don't know if this makes a differance. this is the error now Warning: include(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cms\requires/classes/browser_detection.php): failed to open stream:

Comment: What is the actual full path to your file?  Is it C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cms\requires\classes\browser_detection.php?

Comment: It worked when I added include(ROOT_SYS . '../classes/browser_detection.php')  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you can set an include path

```
$path = '/home/mywebsite/public_html/cms/classes/';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

then

```
include('browser_detection.php');
```