# Can't get require_once called by ajax on localhost to work

Tags: php, ajax, localhost, absolute-path, require-once

I'm almost going crazy here.

I have a simple site locally with a contact form functionality that works perfect with just PHP.

Now I want to call it via AJAX and I always get errors because of the relative paths.

The problem is, that the php file called by ajax has two require_once, which won't work then.

I know that I should use absolute paths to get it working and I tried different approaches suggested by different posts, but all result in an error.

I tried using

`require_once __DIR__ . 'app/config/settings.php';`

I used `define('ROOT_SYS',dirname(__FILE__).'/');` in the index.php making the ajax call and having the require in the php file like this:
`require_once ROOT_SYS . 'class/model/contactForm.php';`

and many other approaches like recommended in this question [PHP include best practices question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644600/php-include-best-practices-question), without success. I get them all to work php side, but when I use ajax it always results in an error like:

**Notice**:  Use of undefined constant ROOT_SYS - assumed 'ROOT_SYS' in **G:\xampp\htdocs\website.de\app\class\controller\contactForm.php** on line **6**

**Warning**:  require_once(ROOT_SYSclass/model/contactForm.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **G:\xampp\htdocs\website.de\app\class\controller\contactForm.php** on line **6**

**Fatal error**:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'ROOT_SYSclass/model/contactForm.php' (include_path='.;G:\xampp\php\PEAR') in **G:\xampp\htdocs\website.de\app\class\controller\contactForm.php** on line **6**

OR

**Warning**:  require_once(app/class/model/contactForm.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **G:\xampp\htdocs\website.de\app\class\controller\contactForm.php** on line **6**

**Fatal error**:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'app/class/model/contactForm.php' (include_path='.;G:\xampp\php\PEAR') in **G:\xampp\htdocs\website.de\app\class\controller\contactForm.php** on line **6**

Either a constant is undefined, because it wasn't included or opening a stream failed.

I mean there must be way to get it working with having a `require_once` in the calles PHP file.

Do you have any experiences you can share with me? I'm really desperate right now.. :(

My folder structure is like this:

```
app
-class
--controller
--helper
--model
--view
-config
-template
docroot
lib
system
-css
-js
index.php
```

My project path on localhost:

```
G:\xampp\htdocs\website.de
http://localhost/website.de/
```

My ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "app/class/controller/contactForm.php",
    data: content
})
```

And the requires in the called contactForm.php how I had them from the start on.

```
require_once 'app/class/model/contactForm.php';
require_once 'app/config/settings.php';
```

There must be some way to get it working, preferably with a setup that works locally and on a webserver.

I know this is a lot to read, so thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `__DIR__` is the way to go. You should elaborate on that statement:

```
require_once __DIR__ . 'app/config/settings.php';
```

I guess you are just missing the `/` because `__DIR__` will give you a path without the trailing `/`. It should be:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/app/config/settings.php';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but with this, I get this error from the start: `Warning
: require_once(G:\xampp\htdocs\website.de\app\class\controller/app/class/model/contactForm.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
G:\xampp\htdocs\website.de\app\class\controller\contactForm.php
on line

Fatal error
: require_once(): Failed opening required 'G:\xampp\htdocs\website.de\app\class\controller/app/class/model/contactForm.php' (include_path='.;G:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
G:\xampp\htdocs\website.de\app\class\controller\contactForm.php
on line 6`

Comment: I guess this is because the file with the require is in a subfolder.

Comment: I stay with `__DIR__`  is the way to go. Just ensure that the path is correct and everything works fine. Is `app` folder in the same folder then the php file?

Comment: As you can see in my question, the file I call via ajax is in `root->app->class->controller/contactForm.php` the files I call via require_once in this file are in `root->app->class->model/contactForm.php` and `root->app->config/settings.php`

Comment: Sorry, building paths from that information is level 1. (Even my mother can). Try a bit and you'll confirm that. I can only say `__DIR__` is the way to go

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry! I was just really slow to catch on. After dealing with this for several hours now, I just somehow got lost with all the error messages.. I got it working now and I guess it's really time for me to stop for today.. ;) Thank you!!

Comment: :) Nice that you found that out for yourself. Now you now!