# What is the best practice to use require_once in a PHP class?

Tags: php

I am wondering which way is the best practice to use require_once in a PHP class.

```
//- location1
require_once(".../mytool.php");

class myclass {

//- location2
require_once(".../mytool.php");

public function __construct()
{
    //- location3
    require_once(".../mytool.php");
}

public function myfunc()
{

    //- location4:
    //- when you need it you call
    require_once(".../mytool.php");

}


}
```

Comment: It would depend upon what is in the script you are including?

Comment: According to your need ..  but you can add this inside method also , According to your needs .. like `if == true ..  require this else require that`

Comment: I tend to use `require` for things like class files (`include` for views) and I generally put them all at the top of the script... since if something is **required** and it isn't there you may as well kill the whole script off immediately.

Comment: Best practice in 2015. and further would be to use `composer` and to create composer packages. You get autoloading out of the box and all your project ever has to do is `require_once('vendor/autoload.php')` which allows you to forget about include, include_once, require, require_once etc. Not to mention that you can develop a library that's reusable and so on. Give it a shot, you won't regret it

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644600/php-include-best-practices-question