# Embedded page in higher directory not using stylesheet

Tags: php, html, css

I have a page which has embedded HTML files from a higher directory. The elements of the files successfully load, however, the stylings of the elements don't. 
The following is the file base.php, which is the page that I am trying to load with the styling. The file header.php is the file which links to the stylesheet.

```
<?php
    require "../header.php";
    require "sidebar.php"
?>
    <main>
        <h1>Test
    </main>
```

Below is the directory layout:

```
media
-styling
--style.css

panel
-base.php
-sidebar.php

header.php
index.php
```

Looking at the terminal, when loading the page, it is trying to get the css from within the panel directory, when it's not referenced as being in there.

```
[Fri Aug  2 00:21:33 2019] [::1]:54765 [404]: /panel/media/styling/style.css - No such file or directory
```

I'm unsure whether I have referenced something wrong or if it's not possible.

Comment: give an absolute path to the style sheet in header.php ie `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/styling/style.css" media="screen">`

Comment: This post might be helpful: [PHP include best practices question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644600/php-include-best-practices-question).

Comment: @tim That solved my problem.

Comment: @showdev Will have a look at this, seems like it could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

try to give the css/js files an absolute path.

For example, you can make a config.php file in the **root** of your website and add those lines:

```php
$aURL = __DIR__."/"; // for absolute URL (give: D:\xampp\htdocs/)
$wURL = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/"; // for other links, for example to another page in your website (give: http://localhost/)
```

Don't forget to include it at the beginning your page. Also, try to `require` only things that are necessary for the page, for example, the database connection, and not the footer, the navbar, etc.

*both variables change if you upload it on your webserver.*

Hope it helpes you.